# Thread.join does not seem to work in my code; am I using it right?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class Automator that can automate a user. I am specifically having problems setting the system clipboard in windows. The Automator class makes use of the ClipSetThread class, which is a thread that sets the system clipboard. A instance of ClipSetThread takes as input a thread, that if null, it joins with (waits for it to complete).

I feel that I am not calling ClipSetThread right because I still have the errors I have had before in its reliability; prior to the ClipSetThread. This code does not throw any errors when it runs, it works about 2/3 of the time though. Other times it will print 1134, _234, or etc. It seems that the threads are not joining (waiting for) each other, or get skipped.

Code:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import org.jnativehook.NativeHookException;
import org.jnativehook.mouse.NativeMouseEvent;
import org.jnativehook.mouse.NativeMouseInputListener;

public class Automator extends Thread implements NativeMouseInputListener 
{
Robot rob = null;
TheAppClass theApp = null;
ClipSetThread lastClipSet = null; 
boolean doit = false;
boolean settingClip = false;

public void run()
{
    try // to make the Global hook
    {
        GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
    }
    catch (NativeHookException ex){theApp.updateOutput("No Global Keyboard or Mouse Hook");return;}
    try // to create a robot (can simulate user input such as mouse and keyboard input)
    {
        rob = new Robot();
    } 
    catch (AWTException e1) {theApp.updateOutput("The Robot could not be created");return;}

    while(true) {}
}

public void setApp(TheAppClass app)
{
    theApp = app;
    theApp.updateOutput("Succesfully started automator");
}

public void setClip(String arg)
{
    ClipSetThread set = new ClipSetThread(theApp, lastClipSet);
    lastClipSet = set;
    set.setClip(arg);
}

public void DOit()
{
    theApp.updateOutput("Starting");
    pasteAtCursorLocation("1");
    tab(1);
    pasteAtCursorLocation("2");
    tab(1);
    pasteAtCursorLocation("3");
    tab(1);
    pasteAtCursorLocation("4");
    tab(1);
    theApp.updateOutput("Complete");
}

public void nativeMouseReleased(NativeMouseEvent e) 
{
    //System.out.println("Mouse Released: " + e.getButton());
    if(doit)
    {
        DOit();
        doit = false;
    }
}

public void pasteAtCursorLocation(String text)
{
    setClip(text);
    rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    theApp.updateOutput("Simulated Paste");
}
public void tab(int numTimes)
{
    while(numTimes > 0)
    {
        rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        numTimes--;
        theApp.updateOutput("Simulated Tab");
    }
}
// Unimplemented
public void nativeMouseClicked(NativeMouseEvent arg0) {}
public void nativeMousePressed(NativeMouseEvent arg0) {}
public void nativeMouseDragged(NativeMouseEvent arg0) {}
public void nativeMouseMoved(NativeMouseEvent arg0) {}
}
```

ClipSetThread:

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;


public class ClipSetThread extends Thread 
{
Clipboard sysClip = null;
TheAppClass  theApp = null;

public ClipSetThread(TheAppClass  app, Thread waitFor)
{
    theApp = app;
    sysClip = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    if(waitFor != null)
        {try {waitFor.join();}catch (InterruptedException e) {}}
}
public void setClip(String arg)
{
    // Two strings that will hopefully never be on the clipboard
    String checkStr1 = "9999999999999";
    String checkStr2 = "99999999999999";
    // When we read in the clipboard we want to see if we change these strings from the ones they
    // will never be, if they do change we read the clipboard successfully
    String clipBoardTextBefore = checkStr1;
    String clipBoardTextAfter = checkStr2;

    // First get a copy of the current system clipboard text
    while(true)
    {
        try 
        {
            Transferable contents = sysClip.getContents(null);
            clipBoardTextBefore = (String)contents.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            try {Thread.sleep(20);} catch (InterruptedException e1) {}
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    // If we failed to change the string it means we failed to read the text
    if(clipBoardTextBefore.equals(checkStr1)) 
        theApp.updateOutput("Could NOT get sysClip text");
    else
    {
        // If we didn't failed to get the current text try to change it
        while(true) 
        {
            try{sysClip.setContents(new StringSelection(arg), null);}
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                try {Thread.sleep(20);} catch (InterruptedException e1) {}
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }

        // Now again check to see the clipboard text
        while(true)
        {
            try 
            {
                Transferable contents = sysClip.getContents(null);
                clipBoardTextAfter = (String)contents.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                try {Thread.sleep(20);} catch (InterruptedException e1) {}
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }
        // If we failed to read the clipboard text
        if(clipBoardTextAfter.equals(checkStr2)) 
            theApp.updateOutput("Could NOT check if sysClip update was successful");
        else
        { // We re-read the clipboard text, see if it changed from the original clipboard text 
            if(clipBoardTextAfter.equals(checkStr1)) 
                theApp.updateOutput("Could NOT successfully set clipboard text");
            else
                theApp.updateOutput("Set Clipboard Text:" + arg + "\n");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You never start the `ClipSetThread` thread, therefore it never runs/completes.  You should also include a flag to indicate if the `Thread` is still running (or have a look at `Thread#isAlive`).  Instead of `Thread`, you really should be using `Runnable` - I think you might like to go back and have a read through [Concurrency in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

Comment: Oh, and if you're going to use `while (true){}` - Seriously consider making the `Thread` a daemon thread, so it will not prevent the JVM from exiting

Comment: I would not want to make ClipSetThread Daemon would I; if I close my program I would choose to close all ClipSetThreads. Because Automator is a Thread could I do a join in its function setClip which would wait for each individual ClipSetThread before continuing?

Comment: There's not reason why not, but you would need some way to signal the thread that it needs to terminate (so it can leave the `while (true) {}` block.  In fact, now I think about it, the `while (true)` block is actually consuming CPU cycles and is very inefficent.  You'd actually be better using a `Object` lock of some kind  ie replace the `while (true) {}` with `waitLock.wait()`.  You would then be able to use `waitLock.notify()` to break the lock and then use `join` on the clip thread...if it were running...

Answer (score 2):

So, firstly, you never call `start` on the `ClipSetThread`.  You should also check to see if the thread is still alive before joining it.

```
public class ClipSetThread extends Thread {

    Clipboard sysClip = null;
    TheAppClass theApp = null;

    private String toClipboard;

    public ClipSetThread(TheAppClass app, Thread waitFor, String toClipBoard) {
        theApp = app;
        sysClip = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        this.toClipboard = toClipBoard;
        // !! Check to see if the thread is also alive before trying to join with it...
        if (waitFor != null && waitFor.isAlive()) {
            try {
                waitFor.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    // You should really put your logic into the `run` method in order to allow
    // the code to actually run in a separate thread...otherwise there is no
    // point in using a thread....
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Two strings that will hopefully never be on the clipboard
        String checkStr1 = "9999999999999";
        String checkStr2 = "99999999999999";
        // When we read in the clipboard we want to see if we change these strings from the ones they
        // will never be, if they do change we read the clipboard successfully
        String clipBoardTextBefore = checkStr1;
        String clipBoardTextAfter = checkStr2;

        // First get a copy of the current system clipboard text
        while (true) {
            try {
                Transferable contents = sysClip.getContents(null);
                clipBoardTextBefore = (String) contents.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(20);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                }
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }
        // If we failed to change the string it means we failed to read the text
        if (clipBoardTextBefore.equals(checkStr1)) {
            theApp.updateOutput("Could NOT get sysClip text");
        } else {
            // If we didn't failed to get the current text try to change it
            while (true) {
                try {
                    sysClip.setContents(new StringSelection(toClipboard), null);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(20);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    }
                    continue;
                }
                break;
            }

            // Now again check to see the clipboard text
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Transferable contents = sysClip.getContents(null);
                    clipBoardTextAfter = (String) contents.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(20);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    }
                    continue;
                }
                break;
            }
            // If we failed to read the clipboard text
            if (clipBoardTextAfter.equals(checkStr2)) {
                theApp.updateOutput("Could NOT check if sysClip update was successful");
            } else { // We re-read the clipboard text, see if it changed from the original clipboard text 
                if (clipBoardTextAfter.equals(checkStr1)) {
                    theApp.updateOutput("Could NOT successfully set clipboard text");
                } else {
                    theApp.updateOutput("Set Clipboard Text:" + toClipboard + "\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

As per our previous converstaion, it's dangerous to use `while (true) {}`, it's also wasteful, as it will consume CPU cycles unnecessarily...

```
public class Automator extends Thread implements NativeMouseInputListener {

    // A "locking" object...
    private static final Object WAIT_LOCK = new Object();

    Robot rob = null;
    TheAppClass theApp = null;
    ClipSetThread lastClipSet = null;
    boolean doit = false;
    boolean settingClip = false;

    public void run() {
        try // to make the Global hook
        {
            GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
        } catch (NativeHookException ex) {
            theApp.updateOutput("No Global Keyboard or Mouse Hook");
            return;
        }
        try // to create a robot (can simulate user input such as mouse and keyboard input)
        {
            rob = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e1) {
            theApp.updateOutput("The Robot could not be created");
            return;
        }

        // This is wasteful...
//        while (true) {
//        }
        // Locks do not consume CPU cycles while in the wait state...
        synchronized (WAIT_LOCK) {
            try {
                WAIT_LOCK.wait();
            } catch (Exception exp) {
            }
        }
    }

    public void dispose() {

        // Tell the thread it can terminate...
        synchronized (WAIT_LOCK) {
            WAIT_LOCK.notify();
        }
        // This will STOP the current thread (which called this method)
        // while the lastClipSet finishes...
        if (lastClipSet != null && lastClipSet.isAlive()) {
            lastClipSet.join();
        }

    }

    public void setClip(String arg) {
        ClipSetThread set = new ClipSetThread(theApp, lastClipSet, arg);
        lastClipSet = set;
        // You MUST START the thread...
        set.start();
    }

    /*...*/
}
```

**Updated**

This code could produce a infinite loop.  What happens if the clipboard does not contain a `String` value??

```
while(true)
{
    try 
    {
        Transferable contents = sysClip.getContents(null);
        clipBoardTextBefore = (String)contents.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        try {Thread.sleep(20);} catch (InterruptedException e1) {}
        continue;
    }
    break;
}
```

You tend to do this a lot.  I might suggest that you provide some kind of "escape" mechanism to allow it to fail after a number of retries...

```
boolean successful = false;
int retries = 0;
while (!successful && retries < 20) {
{
    try 
    {
        Transferable contents = sysClip.getContents(null);
        clipBoardTextBefore = (String)contents.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
        successful = true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        retries++;
        try {Thread.sleep(20);} catch (InterruptedException e1) {}
    }
}
```

**Updated with working example**

Okay, that was fun.  I've put together a (simple) working example.  You will want to open a text editor of some kind.  When you run the program, you have 5 seconds to make it active ;)

The only basic change I've made is I set added a auto delay between events of 250 milliseconds (see `rob.setAutoDelay(250)`.

Now, you could also place a delay between each key event as well, using `Robot#delay`, but that's up to you

```
public class Engine extends Thread {

    private Robot rob = null;
    private PasteThread lastClipSet = null;

    public void setClip(String arg) {
        if (lastClipSet != null && lastClipSet.isAlive()) {
            try {
                lastClipSet.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        PasteThread set = new PasteThread(arg);
        lastClipSet = set;
        lastClipSet.start();
    }

    public void pasteAtCursorLocation(String text) {
        System.out.println("Paste " + text);
        setClip(text);
        rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    }

    public Engine() throws AWTException {
        rob = new Robot();
        rob.setAutoDelay(250);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
        pasteAtCursorLocation("This is a simple test, thanks for watching!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new Engine();
        } catch (AWTException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Engine.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    public class PasteThread extends Thread {

        private String toPaste;

        public PasteThread(String value) {

            toPaste = value;

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Clipboard sysClip = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
            System.out.println("Current clipboard contents = " + getClipboardContents(sysClip));
            sysClip.setContents(new StringSelection(toPaste), null);
            System.out.println("New clipboard contents = " + getClipboardContents(sysClip));
        }

        public String getClipboardContents(Clipboard clipboard) {
            String value = null;
            boolean successful = false;
            int retries = 0;
            while (!successful && retries < 20) {
                Transferable contents = clipboard.getContents(null);
                if (contents.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)) {
                    try {
                        value = (String) contents.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
                        successful = true;
                    } catch (Exception exp) {
                        retries++;
                        exp.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    retries++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(successful + "/" + retries);
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It will only give me an infinite loop if I can find how to make it work reliably. It still seems that I do not get the results from DOit() at all. I seems to paste 4123 quite often. I also tried a [returned ClipSetThread].join() after the pasteAtCursorLocation() with both your code and my code and it still failed.

Comment: The only interaction Automator has with the rest of the program is updating the status and if theApp sets an Automators doit boolean to true it calls DOit(), which is set to false after DOit() returns.

Comment: I've added a working example - stripped back you code a little, but the concept should remain.  I might also recommend that you to a look at the `Executor` API, using a single thread pool executor would solve the need to use `join`...

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try to repeat the Paste action with a sleep 1 second in between

```
public void pasteAtCursorLocation(String text)
{
setClip(text);
rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
theApp.updateOutput("Simulated Paste");

// put in a sleep 1 second here

rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
theApp.updateOutput("Simulated Paste");
}
```

It could be that pasting 2x is giving different results. The reason for this strange behavior could the way Windows manages the clipboard. If pasting 2x the clipboard is giving different result then you know that the root cause for this strange behavior is not to find in your code but how Java and Windows work together.

Comment: That makes it paste twice each time the function is called.

Comment: yes, it is just for testing the reliability of the pasting function. This piece of code will be removed afterwards

Comment: I had a similar issue when working with the clipboard. At hat time it only worked every 2nd try